# Extracting data from background - Facebook

Tags: facebook

I am inspecting a page on Facebook now. These describers indicate that some interesting data is being gathered on the users, but I can't find it.

Is there a way to extract the data? (i.e. userborn, males, females, gpslocation) from the response below:

```
["user","page","group","app","event","friendlist","shortcut"],"browse_functions":{"intersect":{"numParamsUnbounded":true,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":100,"allowsFreeText":false},"fuzzy-intersect":{"numParamsUnbounded":true,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":100,"allowsFreeText":false},"union":{"numParamsUnbounded":true,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":100,"allowsFreeText":false},"fbids":{"numParamsUnbounded":true,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":100,"allowsFreeText":false},"story-fbids":{"numParamsUnbounded":true,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":100,"allowsFreeText":false},"all":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"pages":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"present":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"past":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"future":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"ever":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"ever-past":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"class":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"date":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"after":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"before":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"duration-past":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":2,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"duration-future":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":2,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-age":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-younger":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-older":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-born":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-interested":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-named":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":true},"users-birth-place":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"females":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":0,"allowsFreeText":false},"males":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":0,"allowsFreeText":false},"members":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"friends":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"online-friends":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"non-friends":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"acquaintances":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"close-friends":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"restricted-friends":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"followers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-followed":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"creators":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"admins":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"contacts":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"groups":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"non-groups":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"groups-privacy":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"groups-named":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":true},"groups-about":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"communities":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"communities-named":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":true},"relatives":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"siblings":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"brothers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"sisters":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"parents":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"fathers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"mothers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"children":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"sons":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"daughters":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"aunts":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"uncles":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"nieces":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"nephews":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"cousins":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"grandchildren":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"grandsons":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"granddaughters":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"grandparents":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"grandmothers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"grandfathers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepsiblings":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepsisters":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepbrothers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepparents":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepfathers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepmothers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepchildren":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepdaughters":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"stepsons":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"sisters-in-law":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"brothers-in-law":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"fathers-in-law":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"mothers-in-law":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"sons-in-law":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"daughters-in-law":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"partners":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"boyfriends":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"girlfriends":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-any-relationship":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-dating":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-relationship":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-open-relationship":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"spouses":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"fiances":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-its-complicated":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-civil-union":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"domestic-partners":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"wives":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"husbands":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"students":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":7,"allowsFreeText":false},"employees":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":0,"maxNumParams":5,"allowsFreeText":false},"major":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"degree":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"job":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"schools-attended":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":4,"allowsFreeText":false},"school-location":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"high-schools-attended":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":4,"allowsFreeText":false},"colleges-attended":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":4,"allowsFreeText":false},"grad-schools-attended":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":4,"allowsFreeText":false},"employer-location":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"employers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":3,"allowsFreeText":false},"residents-near":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":4,"allowsFreeText":false},"home-residents":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"hometowns":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"residents":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"current-cities":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"current-regions":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"current-countries":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-of-nationalities":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"nationalities":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"speakers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"languages":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"likers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"exact-page-likers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"job-liker-union":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"listeners":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"readers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"watchers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"actors":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":2,"maxNumParams":2,"allowsFreeText":false},"page_raters":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"commenters":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-religious-view":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-political-view":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"admirers":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"religious-views":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"political-views":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"visitors":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"users-checked-in":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-checked-in":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-visited":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"recent-places-visited":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-recommended-for":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-reviewed":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"pages-in":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-in":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-near":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":4,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-liked":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":false},"places-named":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":true},"places-near-address":{"numParamsUnbounded":false,"minNumParams":1,"maxNumParams":1,"allowsFreeText":true},"gps-location":
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there isn't any information in there. You just copied past some bunch of useless codes.
There is no hidden information, those hashes are only used for their needs, and there's nothing we can actually do to fully analyse it.

Well, we can obviously parse those data, but what will it serve to? You don't even know what does for instance `numParamsUnbounded` means. What do you want to do when you got it parsed? You'll just got the same thing.

Between, it's not HTLM, but HTML, and this code isn't even HTML.

Answer (score 1):

@Jake_Mill22 these are parameters utilized on the Facebook Graph and it's search. It's basically a graph traversal-based search that goes on behind the scenes, and is also based on Set theory. Your search consists of some filterings on entities (people, places, pages, groups, etc) by their semantic relationships to one another. For example:

https://www.facebook.com/search/str/rock%20music/pages-named/likers/str/stack%20overflow/pages-named/likers/intersect

Says show me all people who both like pages on Facebook with "rock music" in their names *who also like other pages* with "Stack Overflow" in their names.

You can put together some pretty interesting queries. Check out here for more info here:

http://booleanblackbelt.com/2015/02/important-facebook-graph-search-developments/